# Raw Line feeds in HTML source

Tags: xojo

I need to take some raw text and convert the linefeeds to HTML breaks.

This does not work.

```
myhtml=Replace(myhtml, chr(13), "<br>")
```

What Does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chr(13) may not be the end-of-lines in your text, also Replace() only works on the first occurence. Try this...

```
myhtml = ReplaceAll(myhtml, EndOfLine.Unix, "<br>")
```

and test with the EndOfLine variations Macintosh and Windows.

Comment: To handle any supported EndOfLine marker, use [ReplaceLineEndings](http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/ReplaceLineEndings) rather than `ReplaceAll`.